# How to set SQL Server to use en_US.UTF-8 in Docker compose

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose

I realize in docker SQL Server linux log, default language is set.

```
spid10s     The default language (LCID 0) has been set for engine and full-text services.
```

I wanted to set it to use `en_US.UTF-8`.

I know how to set it in dockerfile like below

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false \
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

How do I set it in docker compose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set environment variables under [`environment`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) key in compose file.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: 'node:6-alpine'
    environment:
     - LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```